# Faster download sites for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS iso

Tags: iso

I am downloading from here on Windows 10 on WiFi that is showing over 100 Mbps (public library on a sparse Sunday) but is downloading at 300 to 400 KB/second which seems really slow.

Do they have any other sites for faster downloads from Canada?

Comment: Are there many other people trying to use the connection at the same time?  What connection does the wireless system from the library have to the internet?  Has the library limited download speeds for non-library computers?

Comment: Faster downloads than which Ubuntu Download site?